# Can --enable_platform_specific_config be ignored or overriden?

Tags: c++, bazel, bazelrc

My `.bazelrc` file looks like this:

```
# GCC 9.3
build:gcc9 --cxxopt=-std=c++2a
build:gcc9 --cxxopt=-Wall

# GCC 11.2
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-std=c++20
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-Wall
```

On Ubuntu 20.04 I use `bazel build --config=gcc9 //...` to build my workspace. Analogous I use `bazel build --config=gcc11 //...` to build my workspace on Ubuntu 22.04.

Now I was thinking it would be nice if on Ubuntu 22.04 I could build my application by `bazel build //...` without specifying the config `gcc11`. Therefore I changed my `.bazelrc` file like this:

```
build --enable_platform_specific_config

# GCC 9.3
build:gcc9 --cxxopt=-std=c++2a
build:gcc9 --cxxopt=-Wall

# GCC 11.2
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-std=c++20
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-Wall

build:linux --config=gcc11
```

Now `bazel build //...` works on Ubuntu 22.04, but breaks building on Ubuntu 20.04 via `bazel build --config=gcc9 //...`, complaining that GCC does not recognize `c++20`.

Is there a way that the `gcc9` build ignores the `linux` config? Can I ignore or override it?